# microsoft outlook message preview

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

This seems like an easy question but for some reason I have not been able to find the answer. Its simple: when I open outlook 2007 it goes straight to my inbox and loads everything. This message preivew loads and shows the message when i highlight an email (shown below in the picture). It drive[image]s me crazy because i only have so much screen and i dont want it marking emails as read when i havent actially read them. So my question is, can you disable that and how?

anything helps, Hunter

Comment: I am aware that you can minamize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple process, do the following instruction, you can disable or change that viewing pane option.

On the **View** menu, point to **Reading Pane**, and then click **Off**. for disable that one.